# In TypeScript, how to use Function alias with the function keyword?

Tags: typescript

For example, I can use

```
    type Foo = (s: string) => number;

    const foo: Foo = (s) => {
        return 1;
    }
```

But how do I write it in a form like the following:

```
    type Foo = (s: string) => number;

    function foo: Foo(s){    // ERROR
        return 1;
    }
```

and

```
    type Foo = (s: string) => number;

    function foo(s): Foo {   // ERROR
        return 1;
    }
```

also doesn't work. It means returning a function of type `Foo`.

Comment: It looks like you are mixing up responsibilities. If something expects an argument that must satisfy the signature of `Foo`, then that something has to typegaurd it with `Foo`. Currently the requirement is a bit vague to me. Can you elaborate on a situation where this seems useful?

Comment: I posted an answer without asking for your use case, and I agree with @Silvermind that what you want to achieve is vague. Also, why do you want to use `function` if you can use a `const` lambda? Is it because of their difference about `this`? Do you want to define your `foo` function inside a class?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an anonymous function, and store it inside a constant. Otherwise, it's not possible to do this in TypeScript.

Declaring a function will declare its signature type. And you cannot change it, or restrict it.

```
const foo: Foo = function(s) {
    return 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing the two. `(s: string) => number;` is a [function type expression](https://(s:%20string)%20=%3E%20number;) that describes the type of a function.

You can use function type expressions for explicit type declarations like in your first example. This syntax is valid and correct because you explicitely type `foo`. the variable `foo` is assigned to a function of type `Foo`.

```
type Foo = (s: string) => number;

const foo: Foo = (s) => {
    return 1;
}
```

When using the `function` keyword it's exactly the same thing. You can add explicit types to variables.

```
type Foo = (s: string) => number;

const foo: Foo = function (s) {
  return 1;
};
```

However, you cannot define a function and simultaneously speficy it's type because you cannot reassign something to a `function` in TypeScript but only to function expressions. Therefore, there basically is no need to restrict assignments by adding a type either.

```
function foo(s: string) {
  return 1;
}

foo = () => {
  // Cannot assign to 'foo' because it is a function.
  return 2;
};
```